# Weird issue with FPS counter - Limits to 60fps on newer computer

Tags: c++, opengl, counter, frame-rate

I am using an FPS counter class from an open source project and I am having a weird issue. When I run it on my Toshiba Satellite (very fast), the counter seems to max out at 60fps. That's great. Not a problem. I do have another computer, an EEE and it will clock the FPS as high as it will go. In some cases, it can get 132fps and it's a much slower computer. This makes it hard to test for framerate increasing on my main coding computer.

So obviously the issue is something non the code calls that is different across processors. Can any of you with a keen eye find out what it is and suggest alternatives? Thank you so much!

header:

```
#ifndef FPS_COUNTER_H
#define FPS_COUNTER_H

class FPS_COUNTER
{
public:
    void Update(void);                                  //updates counter - call once per frame
    void Shutdown(void);                                //send max, min, average to log
    float GetFps(void)  {       return fps;     }

    FPS_COUNTER() : fps(0.0f), lastTime(0.0f), frames(0L), time(0.0f) 
    {}
    ~FPS_COUNTER()  {}

protected:
    float fps;

    float lastTime;
    long frames;
    float time;
};

#endif  //FPS_COUNTER_H
```

CPP

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "LOG.h"
#include "FPS_COUNTER.h"

extern LOG errorLog;

void FPS_COUNTER::Update(void)
{
    //keep track of time lapse and frame count
    time = timeGetTime()*0.001f;                            //get current time in seconds
    ++frames;                                               //increase frame count

    if(time-lastTime>1.0f)                                  //if it has been 1 second
    {
        fps     = frames/(time-lastTime);                   //update fps number
        lastTime= time;                                     //set beginning count
        frames  = 0L;                                       //reset frames this second
    }

}
```

Edit: I assume it's in the call to timeGetTime() - is there any way to make it behave the way it does on my EER across any processor?

Comment: You probably have vsync on...

Comment: Also use QueryPerformanceCounter for more accurate measurement.

Comment: Have you done any debugging in the Update function?  See if IT is being called more than 60 times per second; from the code, it doesn't appear that it's limiting to 60.  I doubt it would be in timeGetTime() but that is just my gut feeling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if Vsync is enabled in the computer that caps at 60 FPS. Vsync does exactly cap the framerate to the motitor sync rate. To get uncapped FPS, just disable Vsync in the graphics drivers control panel.

Comment: This ended up working. Right clicking on the Desktop. It showed the NVIDIA control .Under manage 3d settings at the bottom I forced vsync off. Thank you for the help and I hope this helps people who need a more specific answer.

Comment: @Moniker why do you need a higher frame rate than your monitor can show?

Comment: @ybungalobill: Why do you ask? There are many reasons to show uncapped FPS.

Comment: @ybungalobill : to test new optimizations, for example.